# Is there an appropriate way to inject a service into singleton?

Tags: ruby, singleton

### Update

I will leave this question for now since there may or may not be a valid use case for something like this.  For my case this was a design problem and instead of using a Singleton, I found a natural location to create an instance of a plain object and pass a reference to it were ever it is needed. Since it's now a plain object I can use constructor injection again.

---

### Original question

I have what I think is an appropriate use of a Singleton.  It's an object that will lazily load the images for folders and filetypes for use in a [JRuby](http://jruby.org), [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt) application.

The class will look something like below.  The methods need an instance of Display to create the images.

The question is, what's the appropriate to inject the Display object and why?
I was thinking of using a `begin ... rescue` block to set the value of @display to nil if the Display is not available and then providing a setter for unit testing.

I always wonder if I am doing something wrong when I think I need a Singleton, even more so when I need to do something unusual with a Singleton, so I would not rule other other options.

```
require "singleton"

class FileSystemIcons
  include Singleton

  attr_accessor :display, :cached_folder_image, :cached_file_images

  def initialize 
    @display = Display.display
    @cached_folder_image = nil
    @cached_file_images = {}
  end

  def folder_image
    unless cached_folder_image
      ...
      self.cached_folder_image = converted_image
    end
    cached_folder_image
  end

  def file_image file_name
    ...
    unless cached_file_images[ext]
      ...
      cached_file_images[ext]
    end
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer contructor injection, whether the object is a singleton or not. That ensures a fully initialized object after creation. Therefore the handling of `Display.display.nil?` should also be part of the constructor.

```
class FileSystemIcons
  include Singleton

  def initialize(display = Display.display) 
    fail(ArgumentError, 'No display given') unless display
    @display = display
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: But you can't call new, that's part of being a singleton (new/initialize) is made private.